# how to open listbox upwards

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have listbox in a popup under a textbox in my project
the text in textbox is searched and results are shown in listbox
my problem is the textbox is nearly at the bottom of my page and when textbox is got focussed the the page move upwards for the textbox is to be seen when virtual keyboard is on the screen however the listbox stays back of the virtual keyboard
can the listbox open upwards so that it goes above the textbox and will be seen when the virtual keyboard is on the screen as well

Comment: Aren't you showing the `ListBox` with custom code?

Comment: You need to adapt the custom code that actually shows the listbox.

Comment: the listbox is shown. if I use laptops keyboard there is no problem but when I use the touch screen virtual keyboard the listbox stays under the virtual keyboard.